# React: Give back the child new inserted element to parent for update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, state

I have a parent component in React who display a list of items, also a state of (selectedList) who give an active class to this list item + display others components depending of the active class. This is the parent component.

In a child, I display the form where I can set a new list and an event onSubmit where I insert it in a Collection (meteor+mongo)

The problem is I can't make a relation between the new item (id) and the parent component cause I would like to select the list newly created (so give active class and display other components). Then I think I should update the state.selectedListId but I don't know how in a child, I can send it to the parent component ?

Here is few lines of codes:

**PARENT ELEMENT (PAGE)**

```
class TodosPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        listSelected: "",
    };
}

selectList(listId) {
    this.setState({ listSelected: listId });
}

renderLists() {
    return this.props.lists.map((list) => (
        <List 
            selectedItemId={this.state.listSelected}
            selectList={() => this.selectList(list._id)}
            key={list._id}
            list={list}
            countPendingTasks={this.countPendingTasks(list._id)}
        />
    ));
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
                <ListForm />
                <ListGroup>
                    {this.renderLists()}
                </ListGroup>
```

**CHILD ELEM (ListForm)**

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nameInput).value.trim();
    Meteor.call('lists.insert', name, (err, listId) => {
        console.log("in method insert = " + listId);
        // HERE I CAN HAVE THE GOOD ID
    });
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.nameInput).value = '';
}

render() {
    return (
        <Form bsClass="col-xs-12" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
            <FormGroup bsClass="form-group">
                <FormControl type="text" ref="nameInput" placeholder="Add New List" />
            </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Then, I can have the good ID in HandleSubmit but I don't know how to give it back to the parent component ..

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the parent (`TodosPage`) pass a function as a prop to its child (`ListForm`).  Then `onSubmit`, have `ListForm` call the function.

```
class TodosPage extends React.Component {
  handleListFormSubmit = (goodId) => {
    // do something with goodId
  }
  render() {
    return <ListForm onSubmit={this.handleListFormSubmit} />;
  }
}

class ListForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // get GOOD ID from the form, then call the parent function
    // [...]
    this.props.onSubmit(goodId);
  }
  render() {
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      {/* form stuff here */}
    </Form>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but I can't set the state in the parent, I could do that too but I have the error: Exception in delivering result of invoking 'lists.insert': TypeError: this.selectList is not a function .. If I do in parent handleListFormSubmit = (goodId) => {
    this.setState(listSelected: goodId);
  } .. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it was pretty simple,

I just used my SelectList function and like @Ty Le said sent it to the child via prop, but to set the new state, **I have to add in my parent constructor**:

```
this.selectList = this.selectList.bind(this);
```

Or I get an error: this.setState is undefined ..

Thanks

Comment: Correct, you need to `bind(this)` if you are using regular functions as in `selectList(listId) {}`. If you use arrow functions (`selectList = (listId) => {}`) I don't think you need to bind this.